# Laravel PHP: Use Dropdown box for displaying results

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a Laravel PHP application up and running fine where all of my results are created, edited and stored just fine.  Now I want to add a feature where there is a dropdown box on the homepage that allows the user to select a category and the homepage will display results depending on what the user selects from the dropdown box.

I have tried finding some documentation on how to accomplish this task but the only possible solution I found was by using AJAX with jQuery to update the results.  I'm wondering if there is an easier, more elegant way of doing this.

**View:**

```
@section('content')

/* New section I recently added for including the dropdown box below */

<div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
            <b>{{'Select a category' }}</b>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">    
            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            {{Form::open(array('route' => 'select_vids_pics', 'files' => true)) }}    

                                <div class="form-group">
                    /* Form Code goes here, 'label' and 'select options' */

                    <div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::submit('Select Category', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}
</div>

{{ Form::close() }}

</div>

                            </td>
                        </tr>    


                    </table>
                </div>            
            </dl>    


        </div>    

    </div>
</div>    


/* Blocks of code below for currently display all results */

<div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
            <b>{{'Overview of Videos' }}</b>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            @if ($allvids->count())
                <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                    <!-- Add this div class to make the table responsive -->
                    <div class = "table-responsive">
                        <table class="table">
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>Edge</th>
                                <th>Stone</th>
                                <th>Category</th>
                                <th>Project</th>
                                <th>Update Video</th>
                            </tr>        
                    @foreach($allvids as $video)
                    <tr>
                         <td>{{ $video->video_id }}</b></td>
                         <td>{{ $video->video_name }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $video->video_description }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $video->video_edges }} </td>
                         <td>{{ $video->video_stones }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $video->category }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $video->video_project }}</td>

                         <td><b>{{ link_to_route("show_video", 'Edit', array($video->video_id)) }}</b></td>
                    </tr>     
                    @endforeach
                    {{ $allvids-> links()}}
                        </table>
                    </div>    


                </dl>
            @else
                <b>{{ 'All Pics Vids' }}</b>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
            <b>{{'Overview of Pictures' }}</b>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            @if ($allpics->count())
                <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                    <!-- Add this div class to make the table responsive -->
                    <div class = "table-responsive">
                        <table class="table">
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>Edge</th>
                                <th>Stone</th>
                                <th>Category</th>
                                <th>Project</th>
                                <th>Update Picture</th>
                            </tr>        
                    @foreach($allpics as $picture)
                    <tr>
                         <td>{{ $picture->picture_id }}</b></td>
                         <td>{{ $picture->picture_name }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $picture->picture_description }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $picture->picture_edges }} </td>
                         <td>{{ $picture->picture_stones }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $picture->category }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $picture->picture_project }}</td>

                         <td><b>{{ link_to_route("show_picture", 'Edit', array($picture->picture_id)) }}</b></td>
                    </tr>     
                    @endforeach
                    {{ $allpics-> links()}}
                        </table>
                    </div>    


                </dl>
            @else
                <b>{{ 'All Pics Vids' }}</b>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



@stop
```

**Controller:**

```
/* This is the only function that is being used in the view above */

public function index()
{
    $allvids = Video::paginate(10);
    $allpics = Picture::paginate(10);
    $this->layout->content = \View::make('home.pics_vids_overview', array('allvids' => $allvids, 'allpics' => $allpics));
}
```

Do I have to add another function/method to my controller for:

1)  Accepting input from the dropdown box that the user selects
2)  Passing that input to the newly defined function and then displaying the results based on that match?

If I have to use the approach above, would my function look something like this?

```
 public function pics_vids_categories()
{
    $input = \Input::all();

    $videos = DB::table('videos')->where('category', '=', $input)->get();
    $pictures = DB::table('pictures')->where('category', '=', $input)->get();

    var_dump($videos);
    var_dump($pictures);

}
```

Like I said, I'm hoping there's a prettier way of doing this.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Laravel to answer completely, but in Zend Framework I'd have a view script that would only render the piece I was replacing, and it would be returned to an Ajax request as an element in the JSON string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may change your `index` method to something like this:

```
public function index()
{
    $vdo = Video::query();
    $pic = Picture::query();
    if($category = Input::get('category')) {
        $vdo->where('category', $category);
        $pic->where('category', $category);
    }
    $allvids = $vdo->paginate(10);
    $allpics = $oic->paginate(10);
    $data = compact('allvids','allpics');
    $this->layout->content = \View::make('home.pics_vids_overview', $data);
}
```

Now if the user selects a category and submits the form then `where('category', $category)` will filter the result; otherwise all records/models will be returned.

Comment: This solution works perfectly!  Its elegant and very effective!  I just want to make one enhancement where after the user selects the category, after the page updates with the returned results the dropdown box stays on the selected category (e.g. The user selects the 'Option2' category in the dropdown box and when the page returns the results, the dropdown should stay selected on 'Option2'.

Comment: You need to use `{{ Form::select('category', $categories, Input::old('categories', $category)) }}`.

Comment: Right now my form is defined as: "{{ Form::select('category', array('Project1' => 'Project1', 'Project2' => 'Project2', 'Project3' => 'Project3', 'Project4' => 'Project4'), Input::old('categories', $category) ,array('class' => 'form-control')) }}  but this is generating an error since '$category'  is undefined.  I am using this form in my view.  Do I need to redfine my 'Form::open' method so that it changes to 'Form::model' instead?

Comment: You need to pass the `$category` from your controller to your view with other variables.

Comment: I tried doing that in my controller just now with '$data = compact('allvids', 'allpics', $category);' but that's not working either.  Do I need to make another variable to hold the '$category' variable in my controller and then pass it to my view?